# How to use include source file in unit tests (Visual Studio 2022)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to add unit tests for a C++ project in VS2022.
I followed the getting started instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-google-test-for-cpp?view=vs-2022).

If I run the default test everything works fine, but if I try and add my code `#include '../ProjectName.cpp'` test explorer no longer detects any tests. Once I remove the include statement it detects the tests again just fine. Am I not supposed to include my code in this way?

Comment: Generally one should never `#include` source files. Instead build your unit-tests like any other multi-source project: Building each source file into an object file, and then link the object files to the unit-test program.

Comment: This question fails to show anything that will meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone here can determine the problem, at most any response will be a random guess as to what the issue is. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Are you using google test or unit test? if it is unit test, I suggest you refer to this [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2022) carefully.